# Handsontable custom validation does not ignore hidden columns

Tags: javascript, angularjs, handsontable

I have searched almost everywhere, but can't find any solution.
In my table I have some hidden columns, it shows when user set one of the option in true.
I need validation for those columns only at the moment when they are not hidden.
so I add custom validation, tried validationCells and find, but that validation does not ignore hidden columns. How can I make the validator return true, when column is hidden?

Comment: Can you provide a plunker or your code? Seem like you can bind the hide propery with the value from the validation, but I am not sure without the code.

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).